# Setting an ImageView above a tableLayout

Tags: java, android

I am struggling to know why my imageView won't appear above the tableLayout.
as part of my assessment I must use RelativeLayout and not linearLayout and I am supposed to set an image above a TableLayout and it isn't working.
This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mad.exercise3.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/imageSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_fn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/TextView_fn" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_fn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ln"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/viewText_ln" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_ln"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView_phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/swapBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/swapBtn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rotateBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/rotateBtn" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is what android studio is displaying.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWyYf.png)

For some reason the imageView and the tableLayout are appearing in the same area, even though I set image view to alignParentTop.

Comment: You must set the TableLayout **below** the ImageView. `android:layout_below:"@id/image"`

Comment: U take 2 **`LinearLayout`** in 1st **`LinearLayout`** U can paste your image code  and 2nd **`LinearLayout`** u can paste your **`TableLayout`**

Comment: And you also need to set the LinearLayout **below** the TableLayout (you need to assign an id to the TableLayout as well)

Answer (score 0):

use an id for the tablelayout then from your image add: `android:layout_above:"id/tablelayout"`

Comment: Tried that the result was the image disappeared and the table layout remained on top

Comment: oh sorry, and make the tablelayout height as ```wrap content```

Comment: Same result, I really don't know why it refuses to move

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mad.exercise3.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_fn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/TextView_fn" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_fn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ln"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/viewText_ln" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_ln"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView_phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/swapBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/swapBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rotateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/rotateBtn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your imageview, and `android:layout_below="@+id/image"` to TableLayout